# Setting title of UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an application which uses a main story board to include a Navigation Controller where the main view is a Table View using a prototype cell content.  Each cell in the table view pushes onto a new view which I have created with it's own set of .h .m and .xib files.

The table view navigation bar has its title set through the story board which works fine.  However, I am having trouble setting the title for each new view after it gets pushed into view.

I have the following in the viewDidLoad method for each view;

```
self.title = @"View Title";
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is the right way. it will work.

Comment: Well I admire your optimism.  But it doesn't work.  Hence the question.

Comment: He's right it should work. alternatively, you can try with setting `    self.navigationItem.title` instead. If it fails as well, we'll need some more code to help you. i.e. didSelectRowAtIndexpath. I recreated the project you described, and self.title works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar in an app I'm working on.  Here's how I'm setting the title:

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"My View's Title"];
```

I thinkt the dot notation equivalent would be something like this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My View's Title";
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tab bar controller, try this:

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
```