# How to Name navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

in my app i'm am basically pushing a viewcontroller from another one
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

The  view controller that results from this call has a navigation bar but I can't name it through the story board. Basically, how do I set the navigation bar's text in code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519512/setting-title-of-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

add this line to viewDidLoad
self.navigationItem.title = @"MyTitle";

Comment: Why not just `self.title = @"some title";`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the storyboard then you can also set the title of the navigationBar just double clicking on the navigationBar. I will work fine for you. try that.